# How to put the site map to every post?

Tags: sitemap

The site map is like this:

```
Menu_A >> Sub_menu_b >> Post
```

It appears in every forum. How can I put this to the top of every post?

I admit that this question is so easy, and I have searched for it but can't find what I want. I have tried using these keyword: *site map, site navigation, site direction* and *site address* but find no help.

Comment: ahhh, that's why I can't search for it. I even don't know that word :D. Make your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, it is written on its wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for **breadcrumbs**, not a site map. There are plenty of plugins in the WordPress repository that might suit your purpose: [`breadcrumbs` plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=breadcrumbs).